# IF conditions not recognising in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm testing my basics of Ruby by writing a simple ChingChongCha program. One of my methods takes the choice entered and turns it into a number (for easy of use for future in the program) however this if statement keeps defaulting to the 'else' condition, even though I can see clearly that if rock is entered it matches the if condition perfectly with ROCK.  Any ideas?

```
def user_choice(choice)
  # 1 is rock
  # 2 is paper
  # 3 is scissors
  userintchoice = 0
  choice.upcase!

  # turns user's choice into an integer
  puts choice #debugging
  if (choice == 'ROCK') then
    userintchoice = 1
  elsif (choice == 'PAPER') then
    userintchoice = 2
  elsif (choice == 'SCISSORS') then
    userintchoice = 3
  else
    puts "Invalid Choice!"
  end

  return userintchoice

end
```

Code calling this method and getting input is:

```
puts "What would you like to choose (input Rock, Paper or Scissors and <ENTER>)?"
userstringchoice = gets()
userchoice  = user_choice(userstringchoice)
```

Comment: Please post the code that calls this function including where you get the user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have to call `.strip` on userchoice because otherwise the string will contain a trailing `\n`.

Comment: Oh fantastic, didn't even think about that. It's fixed. Thank you so much for the suggestion. Something I'm not used to have seeing in Java.